# Prefilling state and country fields on checkout from users account

Tags: expresso-store, drop-down

It seems when a customer checks out using Store after having created their account, the state and country drop-downs default to what we've told them to in the Story settings and not pulling from the user's account info. We've mapped those fields to the member fields.

I'm sure it's a coding thing but I could use some help in figuring this out. What I have now for those drop-downs:

```
<label for="billing_state">State/Region</label> <select name="billing_state" class="store_select" style="width:230px;">{billing_state_options}</select>

<label for="billing_country">Country</label> <select name="billing_country" class="store_select" style="width:230px;">{billing_country_options}</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you emptying the cart between each test? The mapped member fields are only copied into the cart once per order (otherwise it could potentially overwrite data the customer has already explicitly entered).

Comment: Yes, I have made sure to empty the cart between tests.

Would having the defaults set to a state and country possibly be overwriting it?

Comment: I should make it clear that our customers are creating their accounts before they checkout, not during.  Don't know if that would affect anything but thought I should bring it to light.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. Have you mapped both billing and shipping addresses to separate member fields? If I had to guess, one possible cause may be that you have only mapped the billing address fields, and also the "billing same as shipping" option is checked which would be copying the default shipping address over top of the saved billing address.